# Windows 7 can't access shared folder on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows Server 2003 in my local network, made a shared folder with permissions for the specific user.

But the user can't access this shared folder from other Windows 7 PCs on the network. I tried connecting with the user name and password, but the dialog comes again.

My WINS is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to access the share folder by “\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX” and see how it works.
2. Test the issue in Clean Boot.
3. Check if there are any other Windows 7 computers can access it.
4. Change the Network security: LAN Manager authentication level in group policy

---

1).     Click the Start Button, type "gpedit.msc" (without quotation marks) and click OK.

2).     In the "Group Policy" window, double click on "Windows Settings" under "Computer Configuration".

3).     Double click on "Security Settings"-> "Local Policies"-> "Security Options"

4).     In the right panel, double click on the "Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level", please select "Send LM & NTLM Responses".

5).     Click Apply and OK.

6).   reboot the computer to test the issue.